# Can I serialize an interface(_recordset) with TJSONMarshal?

Tags: json, delphi, serialization, recordset, delphi-xe4

I'm trying to serialize objects with TJSONMarshal (XE4) but I have a problem when objects has interfaces properties like _recordset

e.g.

My class:

```
  TFoo = class
  private
    FrsFoo: _recordset;
    FFooProp: integer;
  published
    property rsFoo: _recordset read FrsFoo write FrsFoo;
    property FooProp: integer read FFooProp write FFooProp;
  end;
```

My function:

```
function TestSerialize: string;
var
  JsonMarshal: TJSONMarshal;
  Foo: TFoo;
begin
  JsonMarshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);
  Foo := TFoo.Create;
  Result := JsonMarshal.Marshal(Foo).ToString;
end;
```

It results:

> {"type":"uTest.TFoo","id":1,"fields":{"FFooProp":0}}

rsFoo isn't serialized!

Can I serialize it? or its a limitation of TJSONMarshal?

Comment: Interfaces cannot be readily serialized since they have no implementation, they are merely interfaces. How would you expect the serialization to work? You'll likely need to get the implementing to support another interface the provides serialization services.

Comment: Yes you are right! but I have an implementation for serialize objects into XML using rtti and when "_recordset" appears I save it into a stream (TStringStream) and this is how I get it "serialized". I Think that maybe I can do something like that with TJSONMarshal but "TJSONMarshal.RegisterConverter" only accepts TClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I just want to serialize _recordsets so my solution was:

1) Get all _Recordset type fields:

```
function Test.GetRecordsetFieldsFromObject(
  AObject: TObject): TStringList;
var
  Obj: TRttiType;
  Rtti: TRTTIContext;
  ObjField: TRttiField;
  IntfObj: IInterface;
  rsOut: _recordset;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  Obj := Rtti.GetType(AObject.ClassType);
  for ObjField in Obj.GetFields do
    if ObjField.FieldType.TypeKind = tkInterface then
    begin
      IntfObj := ObjField.GetValue(AObject).AsInterface;
      if IntfObj.QueryInterface(_Recordset, rsOut) = 0 then
      begin
        Result.Add(ObjField.Name);
        rsOut := nil;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

2) Register converter and reverter for each field founded

```
  for FieldName in FieldNameList do
  begin
    JsonMarshal.RegisterConverter(TFoo, FieldName, function(Data: TObject; Field: String): TListOfStrings
    var
      Obj: TRttiType;
      ObjField: TRttiField;
      rsProp: _Recordset;
      strStream: TStringStream;
    begin
      SetLength(Result, 1);
      strStream := TStringStream.Create;
      try
        Obj := Rtti.GetType(data.ClassType);
        ObjField := Obj.GetField(Field);
        rsProp := ObjField.GetValue(Data).AsInterface as _Recordset;
        rsProp.Save(TStreamAdapter.Create(strStream) as IUnknown, adPersistXML);
        Result[0] := strStream.DataString;
      finally
        rsProp := nil;
        strStream.Free;
      end;
    end);

    JsonUnMarshal.RegisterReverter(TFoo, FieldName, procedure(Data: TObject; Field: String; Args: TListOfStrings)
    var
      Obj: TRttiType;
      ObjField: TRttiField;
      rsProp: _Recordset;
      strStream: TStringStream;
    begin
      rsProp := coRecordset.Create;
      strStream := TStringStream.Create(Args[0]);
      try
        Obj := Rtti.GetType(data.ClassType);
        ObjField := Obj.GetField(Field);
        strStream.Position := 0;
        rsProp.Open(TStreamAdapter.Create(strStream) as IUnknown, EmptyParam, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified, 0);
        ObjField.SetValue(Data, TValue.From<_Recordset>(rsProp));
      finally
        rsProp := nil;
        strStream.Free;
      end;
    end);
  end;
```